# How to count occurrences per label?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-wrangling

How can I count the 1's and 0's in column [1] per unique class in column [0]?

```
labels = []

estimator = est.fit(X.iloc[:,1:])
labels.append(estimator.labels_)
labels.append(O)
labels = pd.DataFrame(np.array(labels).transpose())
labels.iloc[:,1] = (labels.iloc[:,1] > 5).astype(int) # Binary GOS-E

x = np.array(labels.iloc[:,1]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(labels.iloc[:,0])
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a piece of your data?

Comment: gotta be a dup `pd.crosstab(labels.iloc[:,0], labels.iloc[:, 1])`

Comment: Yeah most probably a dup from crosstab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.groupby` may suit your needs.

Group by class in column 0, and aggregate using 'sum', which works because only 1s will be 'counted'

`df.groupby(df.iloc[:,0]).agg('sum')` or `df.groupby(df.iloc[:,0]).sum()` should work. You can also use `df['name of column 0']` instead of `df.iloc[:,0]`.